# ConstraintLayout: Set a Start constraint to the End of the longer View, only in XML?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

In order to avoid using several nested layouts, I'm making use of a `ConstraintLayout`.

I have 2 `TextView`, A and B. A is on top of B. A and B contain some text that is defined by the user. So A can be shorter than B, and B can be shorter than A, at execution time.

I have a `Button`, C. C is at right of A and at right of B too. I've wrote, for the moment: `start_ToEndOf(R.id.A)`.

**The problem:** if B is longer than A, C will hide it. What I'm looking for would be a way to tell: "C, your constraint for start is: ToEndOf(R.id.A) if B is shorter than A. Otherwise, it would be: ToEndOf(R.id.B)".

Is it possible using only XML or must I use Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is exactly what a Barrier is for. Have a look at [this](https://constraintlayout.com/basics/barriers.html) tutorial to understand how Barriers work.